# What does this line mean in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

This is the line I am confused with.

```
while (! -e $1/$2)
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It's a bug, and has no useful meaning. It's probably **meant** to be `while [ ! -e "$1/$2" ]` or `while ! [[ -e $1/$2 ]]` or a similar formulation.

Comment: Perhaps there were supposed to be square brackets somewhere instead of parens, and some extra spaces?

Comment: Or maybe is actually `tcsh`, not `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strongly looks like `tcsh` syntax and not `bash`. If it is supposed to be `bash`, the syntax is incorrect.

On the other hand if it is `tcsh`, the line is looping while the file defined by those two arguments `$1` and `$2` does not exist (perhaps $1 defines a folder and $2 defines a file or something similar).

`-e` checks the existence of a file. Source: http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/File_inquiry_operators.html